# How do I extract ROI from fungus image using available MASK of ROI using some ML techniques

Tags: opencv, data-science, mask

I have fungus images data set and each image has its mask of ROI. I want to use the given mask and extract ROI from the fungus image.

[image: This is my fungus image from which I want to extract circled ROI]

Following is the Mask using which I want to extract ROI using some Machine Learning techniques.

[image: This is mask using which I want to extract ROI]

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you would need to do is, train a machine learning model using the masks as an input and the ROI numbers as an output.

For instance, let's say you have a dataset of 30,000 mushrooms with a mask so that only the ROI part is visible.  For each image, you would make its label be the ROI of that specific mushroom (you would need to know this already).

After training, you would be able to input a new image of a mushroom with a mask, and the machine learning model would likely tell you what the ROI is.

If you'd like I can help you with this, I get hired for projects like this all the time.  I would charge you though.

Comment: Can you suggest to me, which machine learning model will be most suitable for training?

Comment: Good question.  You would need to look online for projects similar to yours.  Try searching for machine learning papers that talk about concepts similar to what you are trying to do.  https://ora.ox.ac.uk/objects/uuid:7cb85c63-ced4-4a1f-ab18-f1e1c90420dd/download_file?file_format=pdf&safe_filename=Microscopy%2BCell%2BCounting.pdf&type_of_work=Journal+article  

This one is pretty close ^

Would you be happy with grouping each photo into a range (ROI is between 1 and 5, etc) or do you need an exact value for each photo?

Comment: I need exact value for each photo.

Comment: @zawster Ok then the link I sent you might be applicable for that.  They use images to determine the spacing between cells, which gives them an exact number instead of a category. One consideration too, is if the photo is larger will it look like the ROI is a larger number too?  I might not be a good idea to mask the image as the whole thing might be important for context.

Comment: Tdoggo, Ok Thanks, It means a lot for me.

Comment: Glad to help :)